Turn on double spacing, but not before equations
I'm working on a document that has double spacing. I noticed that when the document is double spaced, the space between the text and the equations in the document is very large. So I end up with a lot of code where I use \vspace with a negative height to manually reduce the spacing:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

Some example text.

\vspace{-10pt}
\begin{equation*}
...
\end{equation*}


\end{document}

Is there a more elegant way to have double spacing between lines of text, but not increase the space between text and equations?

You want the nodisplayskipstretch option, but also to modify \arraystretch.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.604} % reciprocal of baselinestretch

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}

Never leave blank lines before math displays.

Without the option and the change to \arraystretch you'd get

